# Is libphonenumber-js compatible with Angular's buildOptimizer option?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement libphonenumber-js in my hybrid angularjs and Angular 7.2.2 project. It works fine in JIT (`ng serve`) but it gives errors when I enable `buildOptimizer` and `optimize` in `angular.json`.

If I enable only one of the above, it works fine as well.

I have no errors during the build, but when I open the form on the site I have the following in my console.

```
angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:14961 TypeError: (0 , r.default) is not a function
    at MfjL.e.default (isValidNumberForRegion.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:37)
    at e.isValidNumberForRegion (phone-utils.service.ts:32)
    at O (my-account-data-controller.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:48)
    at xt (my-account-data-controller.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:57)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:5117)
    at O.instance (angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:11139)
    at it (angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10002)
    at angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9311
    at angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9176
    at Object.link (angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:28821)
```

We use ng upgrade (https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) in our site.

In the chrome debugger, when I click on `angular.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:14961`, I get to

```
        // Support: IE 9 only
        // console methods don't inherit from Function.prototype in IE 9 so we can't
        // call `logFn.apply(console, args)` directly.
        return Function.prototype.apply.call(logFn, console, args);
```

When I click on `isValidNumberForRegion.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:37`, this is the code:

```
    // `parse` extracts phone numbers from raw text,
    // therefore it will cut off all "garbage" characters,
    // while this `validate` function needs to verify
    // that the phone number contains no "garbage"
    // therefore the explicit `isViablePhoneNumber` check.
    var input = void 0;
    if ((0, _isViablePhoneNumber2.default)(number)) {
        input = (0, _parse_2.default)(number, { defaultCountry: country }, metadata);
    } else {
        input = {};
    }
```

The function that is not found being `(0, _isViablePhoneNumber2.default)(number)`.

I would really like to be able to use both `optimize` and `buildOptimizer` since it is a huge app and this really improves performance. Any idea how to debug that ?

**EDIT:** This may be related https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the library to version 1.7.6 and using the new functions fixed the issue.